# I want to display a table and data between two tables

Tags: mysql

1. I have multiple tables like 100 tables.
2. I have created daily new tables date wise (aa_20190617).
3. I want to display a table and data between two tables.
4. Please explain

Comment: 4, Please explain better

Comment: Which 2 tables? Are you passing dates as parameters? Are you looking for the same news items in 2 tables? Are you looking for most recent and yesterdays tables? etc..

Comment: Why do you create a new table per day?

Comment: Is it a good practise to create new table every day ?

Comment: It is automatically created daily.

Comment: You aren't telling us how you wish to pick the tables required so I am voting to close as question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that they have the same structure you can use union

`(select 'yesterday' as info_time, * from aa_20190617)`

`union`

`(select 'today' as info_time, * from aa_20190618)`